# saying asher yatzar while in an improper state

Tags: halacha, bathroom, asher-yatzar

If you used the bathroom but you're not in the right state to say Asher Yatzar (about to take a shower or not properly dressed). What should you do?

Comment: The answer seems quite obvious to me. You can't say any brachot in the bathroom no matter what "state" you're in. I guess you have to say the bracha when you are done showering and dressed as well as outside the bathroom. (I.e. - you need to be clothed and outside the bathroom.) BTW _ I like your ID, but, if in fact, you know the answer, why are you asking the question? :-)

Comment: Danf the username is meant to be sarcastic. How much time do you have to say the beracha after using the facilities?

Comment: In general you have either up to 30 min or 72 (machlokes haposkim) to say Asher Yatzar after the event. What I am not clear on is that since there is a potential for forgetting when you come out perhaps you are obligated to leave the bathroom first and say a bracha to avoid forgetting

Comment: @AniYodeya - See the emoticon at the end of my comment :-) My apologies for any misunderstandings. Eramm, I think you should post your comment as an answer, even if you are uncertain about what you said about forgetting. Once you remember, you can edit the answer, later.

Comment: @danf, no need to apologize - I saw the emoticon.

Comment: @AniYodeya Is this a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9760/759 ?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Doesn't look like dupe, but, perhaps, related. Within this question, one could, technically, infer that one could say Asher Yatzar in the bathroom or, perhaps, exit the bathroom unclothed to say the bracha. Also see eramm's comment which suggests another answer not mentioned in the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

As @DanF comments "you need to be clothed and outside the bathroom".

[Rabbi Ari Enkin](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/01/the-deadline/) has an extensive discussion of how much time you have.

The main opinions that he quotes are shortened below (see the article for references)

> According to some authorities there is actually no set time limit. The
>   Levush discusses a situation in which one went to the washroom in the
>   middle of the night and rules that the asher yatzar can be recited in
>   the morning even if one does not relieve oneself again upon
>   awakening.[1]
>
> Similarly, there are those who rule that one who goes to the bathroom
>   several times during the night need merely recite it once in the
>   morning.[2]
>
> A number of authorities rule likewise and assert unequivocally that
>   asher yatzar is not subject to any deadline or time limit.[3]
>
> Opinions as to the  time limit vary from  thirty minutes to a
>   seventy-two minutes.[10]
>
> The most widely accepted opinion on the matter is that one may recite
>   asher yatzar up until one feels the urge to relieve oneself anew.[11]

Comment: can one "LeKatchila" rely on those times ? or perhaps the dinim only apply if one *forgot* to say Asher Yatzar right away. In the morning there is an exception since people say it as part of morning brochos but the rest of the day I am not sure one is allowed to delay the bracha until after they are finished with some unrelated activity

Comment: First para of the quoted source reads, "As a general rule, asher yatzar, the blessing recited after one relieves oneself, must be recited immediately once one has washed one’s hands after using the washroom.  There is some discussion; however, as to how long one actually has to recite asher yatzar in the event that for whatever reason it was not recited promptly after relieving oneself." So the delay is bdiavad. Lechatchila the blessing must be recited immediately after relieving oneself.

Comment: Boy...reading all this discussion about Asher Yatzer makes me need to go, myself. But I'm doing it only leshem shamayim - for the purpose of making the bracha, not b/c I really need to :-)

Comment: @DanF, I was actually wondering about that--can you say Asher Yatzar if you made yourself go just to say Asher Yatzar? The Mehaber writes that even if a drop comes out you're hayav to say it...

Comment: @AniYodeya - See what you can learn, here? Now that you made me lose my "kavanah" to go, I'm gonna try, again :-)