# Is there a deadline for Asher yatzar

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, blessing, bathroom

I know there is a deadline for brochois after a meal (until hungry again, 72 min). But if one did not say Asher yatzar, for how much time can one say it?

What are the sources on this subject?

Comment: See [ShA OC 7:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%96_%D7%92).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many opinions ranging from 30 minutes to 72 minutes to until one has the need to relieve oneself again.

From [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchat_Asher_Yatzar#If_one_Didn.27t_Recite_it_Immediately)

- one should say Asher Yatzar immediately after using the bathroom (Mishna Brurah 7:6)
- however, if one did not say it immediately, some authorities hold that one can still say it for 72 minutes after going to the bathroom (Yalkut Yosef Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 6:3 and Halacha Brurah 7:5)
- others say that one should not say it if 30 minutes past after going to the bathroom (Rivevot Efraim 8:2, Ben Ish Chai Vayetze #12)

From [R Ari Enkin](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/01/the-deadline/) (see there for sources)

> According to some authorities there is actually no set time limit. The
> Levush discusses a situation in which one went to the washroom in the
> middle of the night but did not recite asher yatzar at the time due to
> an inability to wash one’s hands. The Levush rules that the asher
> yatzar can be recited in the morning even if one does not relieve
> oneself again upon awakening.
>
> Similarly, there are those who rule
> that one who goes to the bathroom several times during the night need
> not recite asher yatzar each time and need merely recite it once in
> the morning. Again, this is true even if one does not relieve
> oneself upon awakening. Indeed, a number of authorities rule likewise
> and assert unequivocally that asher yatzar is not subject to any
> deadline or time limit.
>
> Other authorities disagree and
> argue that if Birkat Hamazon, which is d’oraisa, has a time limit
> (generally assumed to be seventy-two minutes or until the food is
> digested) then certainly asher yatzar must have a time limit, as
> well. Opinions as to such a time limit vary from a thirty minute
> deadline ranging to those who suggest a seventy-two minute
> deadline. The most widely accepted opinion on the matter is that
> one may recite asher yatzar up until one feels the urge to relieve
> oneself anew.